# Jquery find and output a dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in jQuery, and been trying to get something like this using "find" :

Input :

```
<td>
<a href="person.asp?id=100>Bryan Adams</a> (Singer)
<a href="person.asp?id=100>Bryan Adams</a> (Composer)
<a href="person.asp?id=101>Toto</a> (Group)
</td>
<td>
<a href="person.asp?id=10004>Celine Dion</a> (Singer)
<a href="person.asp?id=10005>John Travolta</a> (Actor)
</td>
<td>
<a href="person.asp?id=10004>Celine Dion</a> (Composer)
<a href="person.asp?id=10005>John Travolta</a> (Director)
</td>
<td>
... and so on
</td>
```

Output will be a dictionary of Name (key) and Professions - appended using comma (value)

```
[Bryan Adams]   [Singer,Composer]
[Toto]          [Group]   
[Celine Dion]   [Singer,Composer]
[John Travolta] [Actor,Director]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "input", is it an HTML String, or actual DOM elements? And is this how you want the output: `{"Toto": ["Group"], "Celine Dion": ["Singer", "Composer"], ...}` ?

Comment: Psst JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries. It has arrays.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Pssst every JavaScript object is a dictionary

Comment: Like i told you @void, i'm a beginner in jQuery, i've been spending hours, i only come up with this : $.find("a[href^='/person.asp']").map( function i,v) { return $(v).text(); });

Comment: @Ragnagord I couldn't consider objects to be dictionaries... You can create your own object type which emulates dictionaries.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Of course they are dictionaries. A dictionary is nothing more than a collection of key-value pairs,  which every js object is.

Comment: @Ragnagord Meh. We're just arguing semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way, using a little regex to extract the role from the parenthesis:

```js
var result = {};

$('a[href^="person.asp"]').each(function(){
  var name = $(this).text(),
      role = this.nextSibling.textContent.match(/\(([A-Za-z\s]*)\)/);

  // If the name is not in the result Object
  if(!result.hasOwnProperty(name)) { result[name] = []; }
  // If the role is defined and not in the roles' array already
  if(typeof role !== "undefined" && role[1].length && result[name].indexOf(role[1]) < 0) {
    result[name].push(role[1]);
  }
});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="person.asp?id=100">Bryan Adams</a> (Singer)
            <a href="person.asp?id=100">Bryan Adams</a> (Composer)
            <a href="person.asp?id=101">Toto</a> (Group)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="person.asp?id=10004">Celine Dion</a> (Singer)
            <a href="person.asp?id=10005">John Travolta</a> (Actor)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="person.asp?id=10004">Celine Dion</a> (Composer)
            <a href="person.asp?id=10005">John Travolta</a> (Director)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` for `td`'s and `a`'s elements and add to object

```js
var obj = {};
$('td').each(function() {
  $(this).find('a').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var value = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    obj[name] = (obj[name] || []).concat(value.trim());
  })
})

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 1) + "</pre>";
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="person.asp?id=100">Bryan Adams</a> (Singer)
      <a href=" person.asp?id=100">Bryan Adams</a> (Composer)
      <a href="person.asp?id=101">Toto</a> (Group)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href=" person.asp?id=10004">Celine Dion</a> (Singer)
      <a href="person.asp?id=10005">John Travolta</a> (Actor)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href=" person.asp?id=10004">Celine Dion</a> (Composer)
      <a href="person.asp?id=10005">John Travolta</a> (Director)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```